# Get parameterized type class of a generic variable

Tags: java

```
public class Foo {

    public <T> void foo(final T t) {
        final Class<T> clazz = (Class<T>) t.getClass();
    }

}
```

I can not understand why `t.getClass()` return a `Class<?>` and not a `Class<T>` (or a `Class<? extends T>`) and so why I need to make a cast.

In which way this cast can fail ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generics in Java is implemented using type erasure.

**The type T does not exist at runtime and the compiler substitutes the `T` with `java.lang.Object`**. So the following method is actually compiled in bytecode:

```
public void foo(final Object t)
```

Comment: Ok but in which way this cast can fail ?

Answer (score 0):

You should look up the term 'type erasure'. The way Java does generics is to compile 'generic' code. That is, it compiles code that will work with any type and does the type checking at compile time.